# How to config CircleCI for multiple subfolders?

Tags: javascript, github, npm, circleci, cicd

I would like to have two circle ci config for two subfolders.
One is for q1, another is for q2. But I have no ideas how to set it up correctly.
I need to push the repo folder to GitHub.

Q1: Are `working directory` and `paths` in two `config.yml` correct?
Q2: Are the folder structure correct?
(I think .circleci could not be placed inside subfolder, am i right? So where should i place them? And how to change the paths and working directory of them?)

My `repo` folder structure is as below:

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── q1
│   ├── .circleci
│   │   └── config.yml
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── yarn.lock
├── q2
│   ├── .circleci
│   │   └── config.yml
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── package.json
└── q3
```

My `config.yml` for `q1` is as below:

```yaml
version: 2.1
jobs:
  deploy:
    working_directory: ~/repo/q1
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:16.9
    steps:
      - checkout
          path: ~/repo
      - run:
          name: install_node_modules
          command: |
            sudo yarn install
      - run:
          name: deploy
          command: |
            yarn run deploy
workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

My `config.yml` for `q2` is as below:

```yaml
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/repo/q2
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:16.9
    steps:
      - checkout
          path: ~/repo
      - run:
          name: Update NPM
          command: "sudo npm install -g npm"
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: npm run test
```

Thank you.

---

### The working combined yaml file

Location of `.circleci` folder: move to under `repo` folder

```yaml
version: 2.1
jobs:
  deploy_q1:
    working_directory: ~/repo/q1
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:16.9
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/repo
      - run:
          name: install_node_modules
          command: |
            sudo yarn install
      - run:
          name: deploy
          command: |
            yarn run deploy

  test_q2:
    working_directory: ~/repo/q2
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:16.9
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/repo
      - run:
          name: install_node_modules
          command: |
            sudo yarn install
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: yarn test

workflows:
  version: 2
  deploy_q1_and_test_q2:
    jobs:
      - deploy_q1:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
      - test_q2:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering about doing something like this. That being said, I think it's impossible. You require a single `.circleci` directory with one corresponding pipeline configuration file. See docs [here](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056463852-Can-I-split-a-config-into-multiple-files-).